# sqlite database lock multithreading question

Tags: multithreading, gcc, sqlite

I've got a "database lock" issue despite the sqlite has been compiled with -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 and each thread uses its own database connection like this simplified code:

```
thread *t = new thread(RandomTextThread);
t.join();
```

and

```
    static void RandomTextThread(void * aArg)
{
    RandomText *rt1;

    rt1 = new RandomText();
    rt1->genRandomText();
}
```

and

```
    RandomText::RandomText() {

    int rc;

    //
    // open the database
    //

    rc = sqlite3_open("mydata.db.sqlite", &this->db);
}
```

So within each thread constructed by the RandomTextThread statical function, a new RandomText object will be created which in turn creates a new sqlite connection stored within the ->db class variable.

Sometimes the code will be execute DML commands. And this works for one thread without an error.
But two or more threads created by the mechanism above fails until as soon the threads will be make concurrent DML.

The system is old, I could compile sqlite 3.27 but I can use only GCC 4.2 with the TinyThread++ solution which in turn uses POSIX pthread.h .
Any help appreciate.

Comment: What, exactly, is the failure? `SQLITE_BUSY`?

Comment: Only one thread can be writing to the database at a time. If you get `SQLITE_LOCKED` or `SQLITE_BUSY` as an error, try the statement again a short while later, or just busy loop until it succeeds or has a different error.

Comment: Yes, it's busy. I've analyzed the problem. Thread 1 ends, but the Thread 2 will be blocked by SQLITE_BUSY endlessly regarding a specified table which was filled prior in thread 1 by sqlite_exec/insert. So it seems there's smth to be freed. But sqlite_exec cannot freed isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`SQLITE_BUSY` is an expected error code when a database is both read and modified at the same time.  Using [Write-Ahead Logging](https://sqlite.org/wal.html), it is possibly to greatly reduce the number of occurrences if there is just one writer and many readers.

[`sqlite3_exec`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) may keep a lock after completion if you have disabled auto-commit mode, for example using the [`BEGIN`](https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) command.  In this case, you must issue a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` command to release the lock.

You can use [`sqlite3_busy_timeout`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) to install a buys handler which performs waiting inside SQLite itself.